# Cannot destructure property of {intermediate value} as it is undefined

Tags: graphql, next.js, strapi

I have just started using graphql for the first time as I have integrated my NEXTJS app with strapi. But I have received this error message `Cannot destructure property 'data' of '(intermediate value)' as it is undefined.`

I followed this tutorial - [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NLXmksU2R-k)

Just modified it to what I wanted. This is my graphql:

```
query {
  posts {
    data {
      attributes {
        heading
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my vs code:

```js
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const client = new ApolloClient({
    url: 'http://localhost:1337/graphql/',
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  })

  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: gql`
      query {
        posts {
          data {
            attributes {
              heading
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `,
  })

  return {
    props: {
      posts: data.posts,
    },
  }
}
```

FULL CODE:

```js
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, gql } from '@apollo/client'

export default function Blog({ posts }) {
  console.log('posts', posts)
  return (
    <div>
      {posts.map(post => {
        return (
          <div>
            <p>{posts.heading}</p>
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const client = new ApolloClient({
    url: 'http://localhost:1337/graphql/',
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  })

  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: gql`
      query {
        posts {
          data {
            attributes {
              heading
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `,
  })

  return {
    props: {
      posts: data.posts,
    },
  }
}
```

I really don't know where to begin with this.

Comment: i've been playing around with it. And, it's not connecting to my graphql and accessing the data so the array is always empty.

Comment: the code                                                                                                             
       export async function getStaticProps() {
    const client = new ApolloClient({
        url: 'http://localhost:1337/graphql/',
        cache: new InMemoryCache()
    });
  const { stuff } = await client.query ({
      query: gql ` 
      query GetPosts {
        posts{
        data{
        attributes {
          heading
        }
        }
      }
    }    `
  });
    return {
        props: {
            posts: stuff.posts
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 2):

1. Firstly check whether or not you are receiving empty data from API.

- If its array, check its length or use methods like `Array.isArray(myArray)`.
- If its object, make a function like this to check objects.

```js
function isObjectEmpty(obj) {
 return (
   !!obj && //  null and undefined check
   Object.keys(obj).length === 0 &&
   obj.constructor === Object
 )
}

export default isObjectEmpty
```

- if the data is empty return `notFound` prop as true to show your 404 page.

```js
// This function gets called at build time
export async function getStaticProps({ params, preview = false }) {
  // fetch posts

  // check validity data
  return isObjectEmpty(pageData)
    ? { notFound: true }
    : {
        props: {
          posts
        }
      }
}
```

2. Secondly add a failsafe mechanism like the use of `optional-chaining` to securely access nested values/properties.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

```js
export default function Blog({ posts }) {
  console.log('posts', posts)
  return (
    <div>
      {posts?.length && posts?.map(post => {
        return (
          <div>
            <p>{posts?.heading}</p>
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: it's showing an empty array, it's not accessing the graphql url

Comment: I think now the issue is specific to Graphql. Try these 2 things. 1. Try with URL `url: 'http://localhost:1337' and `url: 'http://localhost:1337/graphql'` 2. Try making n/w request directly using `fetch` API. `const data = await fetch(GRAPHQL_URL, { method: 'GET' })
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .catch(error => console.error('Network Error:', error))

  const posts = data?.posts`

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same error while testing using Jest.

It turns out I was mocking all of graphql, but I had to specifically mock the return value.